# Refactoring a method to return a value from addEventListener in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am checking the Network Status in my Angular application from network.service.ts

// network.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class NetworkStatusService {
public status: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

public appStatus() {
    window.addEventListener('online',  this.networkStatusChanged.bind(this));
    window.addEventListener('offline', this.networkStatusChanged.bind(this));
  } 

  public  networkStatusChanged(): void {
    this.status.next(!navigator.onLine);
  }
}
```

In my component, I am injecting this service and in ngOnInit,

I am calling this appStatus method of the service and then subscribe to status (BehaviorSubject) to get the value.

In my component:

```
  public ngOnInit() {
    this.networkService.appStatus();
    this.networkService.status.subscribe((x)=>{
      console.log('status here', x);
      if(x) {
      // do something
      }
    });
  }
```

This works and logs the boolean value whenever the application online/offline. But the problem is I would have to call this method and then subscribe & unsubscribe in pretty much every component.
I know addEventListener does not return a value but is there a way to refactor this, so that I just call appStatus() from the component and it returns a boolean value (true/false) whenever the application is offline/online?

Comment: it's a bit unclear what exactly you want to achieve, are you trying to avoid subscribing to status in every single component and at the same time want to keep track of network status in those components?

Comment: Hi, Yes I do not want to subscribe to the status in every component and trying to find a way if I just call the method in service from ngOnInit and it returns a boolean value as per the network status.

Comment: well that's quite straight forward your appStatus method can just return `navigator.onLine` but if you want to keep listening to the changes in network in your component and also don't want to subscribe to those changes then don't you think it'll be contradictory, you'll need to subscribe.

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a getter in any component where you want to call appStatus, it will return value of network status.

```
   public get appStatus () {
      return navigator.onLine
    }
```

But if you need to listen every time BehaviorSubject emits value, u need to subscribe.

Answer (score 0):

Add your listeners inside service class constructor instead of appStatus() function. This way you don't have to call it every time or from every component.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class NetworkStatusService {
public status: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);


  constructor() {
    window.addEventListener('online',  this.networkStatusChanged.bind(this));
    window.addEventListener('offline', this.networkStatusChanged.bind(this));
  }

  public  networkStatusChanged(): void {
    this.status.next(!navigator.onLine);
  }
}
```

Now subscribe **this.networkService.status** from any component as you are doing currently.